# Managing the time that user has to wait to play if he exceeded his "Lives" (Android game)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, time

**I'm currently developing a quiz game for android.**
the player has a specific number of "lives" in the beginning and whenever his answer for a question is wrong, he lose one of his "lives".
And if the number reaches zero he will have to wait some time to be allowed to play again.
I came up with an idea that whenever the lives count reaches zero i save that time added to the time user have to wait.
Then every time i check the Difference between the current time and the saved one.
But if the user changed the date he will pass this restriction.

Is there a better idea for preventing that.

Code:

```
private void heartsManager() {
    falseB.setEnabled(false);
    trueB.setEnabled(false);
    heartsCount = Utils.getIntFromPreferences(this,5,"Hearts","SHARED_SAVED_DATA");
    long TimeToUnlock = Utils.getLongFromPreferences(this,0 ,"Saved_Time", "SHARED_SAVED_DATA");
    Date curDate = new Date();
    long currentTime = curDate.getTime();
    if(currentTime<TimeToUnlock) {
        timeDifference = (TimeToUnlock - currentTime);
    }else{
        timeDifference=0;
    }
    if(heartsCount<1&&levelCompleted==levelID) {
        timeCountDown();
    }else {
        hourGlassToHeart.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart);
        hearts.setText(String.valueOf(heartsCount));
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                falseB.setEnabled(true);
                trueB.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }, 1500);
    }
}

private void timeCountDown(){
    new CountDownTimer(timeDifference, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            hearts.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d",(millisUntilFinished / 600000),(millisUntilFinished % 60000 / 1000)));
            hourGlassToHeart.setImageResource(R.drawable.hourglass);
        }
        public void onFinish(){
            hourGlassToHeart.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart);
            falseB.setEnabled(true);
            trueB.setEnabled(true);
            heartsCount=heartsCount+1;
            hearts.setText(String.valueOf(heartsCount));
        }
    }.start();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a BroadcastReceiver that detects if the user changed the time (Intent.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED) of the phone. If the user did that, don't trust his local time and query your server for the correct time. Probably meaning that you won't let the user play unless he connects to your server.

```
public class TimeChangedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED))
        {
             //set time changed flag here.
        }
    }

}
```

Don't forget to add the BroadcastReceiver to your manifest or start it.

Opinion: I don't think there's a way around users that change time. Most in the industry accept it because the average user doesn't know about this 'hack'.

Comment: Thank you. I also thought that there is no solution for this except depending on internet time. BroadcastRecever will do fine for now, thanks alot